# Would you term Google's Captchas as Turing Test?

Tags: terminology, turing-test, google

Quoting from Wikipedia page on [Turing Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test)

> The Turing test, developed by Alan Turing in 1950, is a test of a machine's ability to exhibit intelligent behaviour equivalent to, or indistinguishable from, that of a human. Turing proposed that a human evaluator would judge natural language conversations between a human and a machine designed to generate human-like responses. The evaluator would be aware that one of the two partners in conversation is a machine, and all participants would be separated from one another. The conversation would be limited to a text-only channel such as a computer keyboard and screen...

The definition made me wonder if we would term the **captchas** that show up on Google here it gives textual instructions to the user, bot or not, asking them to select images containing a specific object out of the given set of images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the [standard Turing test (or imitation game)](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/471/papers/turing.pdf), the interrogator can ask multiple *arbitrary* questions, while, in the case of captchas, usually, there's only one question or problem. Additionally, in the Turing test, the interrogator interactively communicates with both the human and the machine. Furthermore, captchas do not test the conversational skills but only the visual ones of the AI. Therefore, the existing captchas are **not** an example of the *standard* Turing test.